# After pushing in git, The 'git tag' isn't displayed in remote

Tags: git, tags

It is successful to use the command 'git push origin tagname', but The tag isn't displayed in remote

Comment: What remote are you using? Can you show us the commands you used and their outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Tags aren't push automatically. Use `git push --tags`

Answer (score 0):

To push a single tag:

```
git push origin <tag_name>
```

And the following command should push all tags (not recommended):

```
git push --tags
```

Comment: After 'git push origin <tag_name>'，The <tag_name> isn't displayed in remote